# Kinfu with PMD Camboard Nano

Tags: c++, ubuntu, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

**Problem**

I wan't to use kinfu with my miniTOF camera (model: *PMD Camboard Nano*). I set up everything and kinfu works with *Kinect*.

**Solution!?**

Tweak *openni_launch* package to somehow start my camera or remap my camera outputs to the *openni's* one in order that I can use with the *kinfu* algorithm.

If you need more information just ask, don't simply vote down.

**Post ideas, solution anything that can be useful.** The question is not trivial.

**UPDATE**

Any useful information gets rewarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ROS node for PMD camera](https://github.com/taketwo/pmd_camboard_nano/blob/master/src/pmd_camboard_nano.cpp)

[Multiple solutions from Cayim for those who can enter the forum](https://www.cayim.com/forum/index.php?/topic/45-pcl-openni-and-camboard-nano/page-2?hl=kinfu)

These are sugestions only, ... not full solutions.

**Updated!!!**

Answer (score 3):

you might also want to post your question on [cayim.com](http://www.cayim.com/forum) - the CamBoard nano developer community.
I´m sorry I can´t provide further help.
LowKnee